# Change <class 'numpy.ndarray'> to <class 'numpy.float64'>

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a numpy.ndarray to a numpy.float. The numpy.ndarray looks like this:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[0.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 ...
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
```

I want to convert it in a numpy.float like this:

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
[0.0, 1.0, 1.0, ... , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Can somebody help me?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Your example of a float is still a ndarray, just with one less dimension. Also, the original 2D-array is already appears to have dtype=numpy.float. It is unclear what the problem and goal is.

Comment: `np.float64` is just 1 number.  Looks like you just want to change shape, from (n,1) to (n,).

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing array *type* with array *data type*.

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([[0.],
    [1.],
    [1.],
    [0.],
    [0.],
    [0.]]
)
print(type(ar))
print(ar.dtype)
print(ar)
ar_float = ar.flatten()
print(type(ar_float))
print(ar_float.dtype)
print(ar_float)
```

As you can see, in both cases type of the array is `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` but its data type is `float64`. Main difference about those 2 arrays is their shape.